# Add a prefix to column names

Tags: r, dataframe

When reading the following [helpfile](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/colnames.html) it should be possible to add a prefix to the column names :

```
colnames(x, do.NULL = TRUE, prefix = "col")
```

The following doesn't work for me. What am I doing wrong here?

```
m2 <- cbind(1,1:4)
colnames(m2, do.NULL = FALSE)
colnames(m2) <- c("x","Y")
colnames(m2) <- colnames(m2, prefix = "Sub_")
colnames(m2)
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You have misread the help file. Here's the argument to look at:

`do.NULL`: logical. If `FALSE` and names are `NULL`, names are created.

Notice the **and** in that description. Your names are no longer `NULL`, so using prefix won't work.

Instead, use something like this:

```
> m2 <- cbind(1,1:4)
> colnames(m2) <- c("x","Y")
> colnames(m2) <- paste("Sub", colnames(m2), sep = "_")
> m2
     Sub_x Sub_Y
[1,]     1     1
[2,]     1     2
[3,]     1     3
[4,]     1     4
```

Comment: +1, As I understand it, `prefix` is only used to create names for columns that don't have one.

Comment: Indeed, I should have read that sentence more carefully, thanks!

Comment: How would you paste() to the end of colnames?

Comment: `colnames(m2) <- paste(colnames(m2), "sub", sep = "_")`

Comment: is there an answer for this using `dplyr`... i'd like to add this as the final step to one of my functions

Answer (score 62):

I will add a `tidyverse` approach to this problem, for which you can both add suffix and prefix to all column names. The following adds a prefix in a `dplyr` pipe.

#### dplyr 1.0.2 and beyond

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(3, 4))

## Adding prefixes
df %>% rename_with( ~ paste0("a", .x))

## Adding suffixes
df %>% rename_with( ~ paste0(.x, "a"))
```

If you want to have separators such as underline, you can use `paste` as well with the `sep` argument.

---

#### Before dplyr 1.0.2 update

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(3, 4))
df %>% rename_all( ~ paste0("a", .x))
```

Adding suffix is easier.

```
df %>% rename_all(paste0, "a")
```

Answer (score 16):

The updated `tidyverse` method (with `dplyr 1.0.2`) uses `rename_with()` as the `rename_all()` function has been superseded.

```
iris %>% rename_with( ~ paste("Sub", .x, sep = "_"))
```

Comment: In my opinion, this is clearly the simplest and cleanest solution to the problem. It also works for "postfix" with `paste(.x, "Post", sep = "_")`

Answer (score 4):

The `stats::setNames` function works just fine for this, and is in fact much quicker than the alternatives.

```r
iris.dt <- data.table::as.data.table(iris)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  
  base = colnames(iris) <- paste("Sub", colnames(iris), sep = "_"),
  stats = setNames(iris, paste("Sub", colnames(iris), sep = "_")), 
  dplyr = dplyr::rename_with(iris, ~ paste("Sub", .x, sep = "_")),
  datatable = data.table::setnames(iris.dt, paste("Sub", names(iris.dt), sep = "_"))
  
)
#> Unit: microseconds
#>       expr     min       lq       mean   median      uq        max neval cld
#>       base  11.094  16.2140   21.62408  19.2010  23.681     65.707   100   a
#>      stats   8.107  13.8670   17.40435  16.6405  19.841     39.254   100   a
#>      dplyr 786.772 842.8785 5236.67222 877.0130 984.959 402378.407   100   a
#>  datatable  40.961  49.9200   84.06237  62.2935  73.600    834.560   100   a
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>