# Adding a prefix to certain column names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a problem very similar to this one: [Adding a prefix to column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872081/adding-a-prefix-to-column-names).
I want to add a prefix to the column name - the only difference is, that I dont want to add the prefix to every column I have. Here the same minimum, reproducible example as in the question mentioned above:

```
m2 <- cbind(1,1:4)
colnames(m2) <- c("x","Y")
```

Resulting in:

```
     x Y
[1,] 1 1
[2,] 1 2
[3,] 1 3
[4,] 1 4
```

The code for adding a prefix "Sub" to both columns would look like this (as suggested by the user A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1):

```
colnames(m2) <- paste("Sub", colnames(m2), sep = "_")
```

Resulting in:

```
     Sub_x Sub_Y
[1,]     1     1
[2,]     1     2
[3,]     1     3
[4,]     1     4
```

How can I add a prefix "Sub" only to the first column? I tried the following:

```
colnames(m2[,1]) <- paste("Sub", colnames(m2[,1]), sep = "_")
```

Result of the code: No Warning, no error but no prefix as well. Any suggestions? Besides base r any suggestions using dplyr are appreciated as well. Please let me know if you need any further information. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```r
colnames(m2)[1] <- paste0("Sub", "_", colnames(m2)[1])
# or if you prefer paste
#colnames(m2)[1] <- paste("Sub", colnames(m2)[1], sep = "_")
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
m2 %>%
 as.data.frame() %>%
 rename_at(1, ~ paste("Sub", ., sep = "_"))

  Sub_x Y
1     1 1
2     1 2
3     1 3
4     1 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Also `paste()` accepts vectors so you could do:

```
colnames(m2) <- paste0(c("Sub_", ""), colnames(m2))
```