# Adding a prefix to a column name using the value of different column using dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

There is a thread for "Adding a prefix to column names", but the solutions are limited to adding fixed strings as the prefix or postfix. Is is possible to add the value of another column as a prefix to a column name?

For example, I have a column named `sum`, and another column named `time_period` with values of `year`, and `month`, depending on the dataframe. I am hoping to create new columns like `year_sum` and `month_sum` dynamically. A `dplyr` solution would be ideal but not necessary.

Already tried the following thread and related threads:
[Adding a prefix to column names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872081/adding-a-prefix-to-column-names)

```
df <- tibble(sum = c(150, 175, 200), time_period = c('year', 'year', 'year')) %>%
        rename_at(vars(sum), function(x) paste0(time_period, x)) %>%
        glimpse()
```

I get the following error:

> Error in paste0(time_period, x) : object 'time_period' not found

I am expecting that column `sum` is renamed to `year_sum`.

Comment: Can you show us your expected output?

Comment: Can you show what your expected output would look like? Preferably with an example that also includes month in the time period.

Comment: What happens if `time_period` has values other than `year`?

Comment: For the example above, my expected output would be:  year_sum time_period  150 year  11 year 14 year.  If the time_period had values of "month" instead, I would expect: month_sum time_period  150 month  11 month  14 month.  For my exact dataframe, the solution from @Cettt actually should do the trick as I'm not expecting mixed values of time_period within each dataframe. This solution is going into a generalized function which is why I'd like it to be dynamic. (Sorry not sure if this format is valid - first post on SO and trying to figure out the markdown formatting now).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a workaround solution. It only looks at the first row of `time_period` and takes what ever value it finds there:

```
df %>% {rename_at(., vars(sum), function(x) paste(pull(., time_period)[1], x, sep = "_"))}

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  year_sum time_period
     <dbl> <chr>      
1      150 year       
2      175 year       
3      200 year
```