# Adding a suffix to a selection of column names in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14872081/add-a-prefix-to-column-names) great post showed me how to add prefixes to column names using dplyr. But what if I only want to add prefixes to *some* of those column

```
library(dplyr)

(df <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2), y = c(3, 4), z = c(5, 6)))

#   x y z
# 1 1 3 5
# 2 2 4 6
```

Now if I want to add a prefix to all of these I can do this.

```
## Adding prefixes
df %>% rename_with( ~ paste0("a", .x))

#   ax ay az
# 1  1  3  5
# 2  2  4  6
```

But what if I only wanted to add a prefix to columns `x` and `y`? Some sort of select syntax? I tried

```
df %>% rename_with(across(cols = c("x", "y")),
                   ~ paste0("a", .x))
```

But got an error saying `across()` could only be used inside `dplyr` verbs, and I guess `rename_with` isn't one of those

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may select columns in `rename_with` -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% rename_with(~paste0("a", .x), c(x, y))

#  ax ay z
#1  1  3 5
#2  2  4 6
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak Shah. Saved my life for the 100th time